# DataTable width on different screens

Tags: plotly, width, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have this DataTable:

[image]

As you can see, the `width` looks good on my screen.
However, some people complain that they have to use the `right/left` arrows to see the whole table.

At the moment I'm using `vw` units to define the table width, but the problem still remains.
I don't know if there's a solution for this or if it depends on each screen resolution.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make it so cell content spans multiple lines if there is not enough horizontal space.

Example given in the documentation:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    style_cell={
        'whiteSpace': 'normal',
        'height': 'auto',
    },
    data=df_election.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df_election.columns]
)
```

See the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/width) for a lot of options on styling the width of a datatable.